# AWS Amplify configurations: How to assume IAM credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

How can I configure EC2 instance to use IAM roles and how can the Amplify CLI automatically assume the IAM credentials for my application and eliminating the need to manually provide credentials.

I tried to create an amplify project via EC2 instance and I did not want to use the IAM credentials. How can I whitelist this problem and create an amplify project.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the IAM Role to the Amazon EC2 instance? Once you do this, any software on the instance that uses an AWS SDSK will automatically access the provided credentials.